# (X)Ubuntu some graphics only render on 2/3 of screen

Tags: graphics, xubuntu, virtualbox, xfce, hardware-acceleration

### Short

On Xubuntu 14.04 running on a Inspiron i3531-1200BK laptop , the xfce log-in screen only renders 2/3s of the screen, but issue is not present for xfce desktop after logging in. Issue also exists with other 3d applications. How can I fix this?

### Longer

I'm going to list everything I know about this laptop which is running XUbuntu 14.04 on Dell Inspiron i3531-1200BK.

The log in screen only renders 2/3s of the screen. After log in this fixes itself with a much of random-looking graphics resizing. I thought this was weird, but since it only existed on the log in screen I ignored it at first. This issue has been present since installing Xubuntu.

After about 3 weeks of owning this device, and updating when it xubuntu every update, I found that even with the default install setting (I think LVM was actually also checked if that matters) I could not update the OS because of having less than 1mb of extra space. Since I did the default partitioning, with entire 500gb HDD and still greater than 400gb still free, I was surprised. I then used

```
dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

based on askubuntu help (I don't recall which, I just got that from the terminal past commands log) from someone else's Question. This seemed to let the updates go though, but uninstalled g++ and other things which I had to reinstall later. I don't know if this messed stuff up more, but the log in graphics issues predate it.

After installing Oracle VM Virtualbox, I noticed if I use 3D graphics acceleration the same thing happens if I go from FULLSCREEN mode to SCALED mode I get the same issue. Instead of turning to normal scaled mode it takes up 2/3 the screen and cannot seem to be put back to fullscreen mode. Interestingly (and frustratingly) it also looses the ability for the mouse to work. I had thought the machine froze, but noticed I could TAB through stuff on the VM. After pressing the HOST key, and then ALT + TAB , I noticed that the VM was now treated as two programs in addition to the virtualbox config/launcher window.

This seems to be an issue with lots of 3d things.

I'm not sure what you gals/guys need to know more (likely from terminal), but if you let me know, I will run them and update this.

`$ uname -a
Linux user 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

glxgears seems to run but when I close it using the 'x' button on the window, it crashes

`$ glxgears
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0.0"
      after 380 requests (380 known processed) with 0 events remaining.`

PS This may or may not be useful too:
Only other bug I am aware of is that for some reason the wifi password dialog box only allows for logging into wifi that uses specific number of characters, eg. 6 character passwords grey out the OK button and cannot be used but 5 or 7 character passwords are OK.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is saying temporarily unavailable is because you are stopping the process by clicking the [x], when it is running and you let it run for a couple of seconds you see the frame rate in the terminal, right?  When you stop the process then it cannot tell you the frame rate, therefor the resource becomes unavailable, nothing to worry about.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Pilot6 It looks like he is trying to answer the question to me, or at least a part of it.